# How do I do css transition delays in reverse other than for hover?

Tags: css, transition, delay, reverse

I've got a vue.js application in which I'm trying to figure out how to reverse a delayed css transition. I have a div whose width contracts when the user clicks the close button. Then the height contracts. The height has the delay on it because I want to wait for the width to contract before contracting the height.

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

When the user clicks the question mark icon, I want the reverse to happen. The height should expand immediately and then the width expands after a delay.

All the examples of how to do this which I find on google deal with hover transitions. They say to put the reverse transitions in the hover class. All demos I've seen work. But there must be something different about how this works when it comes to transitions that are trigger by something other than hover. In my case, the trigger is a mouse click. And the online solutions don't work. What happens instead is that the reverse transition placed in transitioned-to class seems to override the original transition--which means the original transition contracts the height first (which looks terrible considering the content doesn't fit) then the width.

Here is my code:

```
.need-help-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 120px;
    ...
    transition: right .5s, height .5s .5s;
}

.need-help-container-closed {
    right: -360px;
    height: 50px;

    transition: right .5s .5s, height .5s; // <-- doesn't work
}
```

```
<!-- need help box -->
<div class="need-help-container" :class="{'need-help-container-closed': needHelpClosed}">
...
    <!-- close button -->
    <div ...>
        <v-icon @click="needHelpClosed = true" ...>close</v-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should the same solution to the examples involving hover work here? If so, why would it not be working for me? If no, what would be an alternate solution for my case?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the class name of your closed container?

Comment: need-help-container-closed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.need-help-container-closed:active{
//your code here
}
```

Use :active in place of hover.Did it work?

Comment: Not sure how to implement :active. I replaced all instances of need-help-container-closed in the code above with need-help-container:active but that just stopped the container from collapsing. Isn't :active only applicable to hyperlinks?

Comment: Yeah, :active makes the item clickable.You have said that in the tutorial, they provided the code for :hover.You have to put that code in the : active.I have updated my answer.

Comment: I need your html css and js of this chatbox.I will try fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I created a separate class just for reversing the order of the delay:

```
.need-help-container-opening {
  trnasition: right .5s .5s, height .5s;
}
```

Then I added the class based on a new variable:

```
<div class="need-help-container"
  :class="{'need-help-container-closed': needHelpClosed, 'need-help-container-opening': needHelpOpening}"
  @transitionend="needHelpOpening = false">
    <div class="faq-icon-container need-help-item"
      :class="{'faq-icon-container-closed': needHelpClosed}"
      @click="needHelpOpening = true; needHelpClosed = false">
        // Question Mark icon... click to open
    </div>
...
</div>
```

So I have a variable called needHelpOpening which I set to true when the user clicks the question mark to open the box. When this variable is true, the box gets the need-help-container-opening class which reverses the delay. Finally, when the transition ends, the transitionend event fires and I catch it in the main div for the box and set needHelpOpening to false so that the original delay order is reset.